# Not able to integrate HMS Computer Graphics kit sample code since Skybox making procedure is not released with the sample code in dev doc

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to integrate Huawei Computer Graphics (CG) kit but not able to implement steps explained in the developer document. Document explained configuration procedure for the skybox but making a skybox process is not released with the sample code and there is no reference material provided.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  [website](https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/playground_textures#cubetextures) provides the visualized displays for skyboxes for learning purposes.

1. Download a cubemap skybox and edit the .cub configuration file as follows –

   width=512

   height=512

   depth=6

   mipmap=1

   face=6

   channel=4

   suffix=.png

   Here the width and height must be the same as the png image size of the first-level mipmap of the skybox.

Name the picture according to the guide, as follows:

[image]

Save these files in the env directory and copy those to the cubemap directory of the sample project.
Please note : CG Kit supports only four-channel PNG images. If your PNG images are not four-channel, use Paint or any other graphics editor and save those as .png files to convert them into four-channel PNG images.

2. Modify the Skybox
   Modify the configuration and cube model in the CreateSkybox method of MainApplication.cpp file as

String modelName = "models/cube/cube.obj";

Set the environment map in the MainApplication.h file as

String m_envMap = "cubemaps/env/env.cub";

This name should be the same as used to create the skybox.